# Rails setting a belongs_to one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i'm encountering trouble with this association:

Branch belongs_to Referent
Referent has_many Branches

In my case a Branch belongs to one Referent only

i need to do

```
branch.referent.id
```

that for the moment return nil as Branch can have for Rails many Referents

What is the best solution?

Comment: ups, i didn't knew this feature...

Comment: I think that should be working. How are you setting `branch` in your controller? Can you post that code?